# appcompat-v7:27.1.1 CardView not showing in previous apis

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, build.gradle, android-cardview

I'm compiling for SDK 27 and I used these dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

However, I can't change 27 to a previous version as it spits an error with some cache problem. The program runs and I can see the card view on my phone as it's running the latest SDK. But when I take a phone with an older SDK (say 6.0), the cardview does show. This is my output if I change `targetSDK` to **23** and `compileSDK` to **23.** and:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1  
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

This is the error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.","sources":[{"file":"/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/1642e61f47dd91a1acce6e369ec672e9/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":431,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":652}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

Comment: are you using google() in your gradle project?

Comment: this is my gradle:

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: so yes im using google

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.1.1'
```

Comment: if this doesnt work please post your gradlw files so we can help you